Logistic Regression - categorical predictors
I'm looking for resources on general guidance for how to perform and interpret multiple logistic regression using SPSS, using categorial predictors. I have 2 categorical predictor variable. Each categorical predictor has three groups or categories. (My outcome is binary, yes or no.) Each predictor category are likert-type categories.
Predictor 1
Unlikely,
Neither likely or unlikely,
Likely
Preditor 2
Slightly concerned,
Somewhat concerned,
Very concerned

UCLA has a great resource that includes a multi-category predictor like yours: https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/spss/dae/logit-regression/

@Noah Thank you!

The UCLA page, like most articles about this sort of thing, treats the categorical independent variable as nominal and ignores the ordering of the IV. Methods for ordinal IVs are less common. One that I have used sometimes is optimal scaling.

Thank you, I'm starting a new question looking for resources on this
